# adding space and new line in html editor asp.net ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to `insert blank characters` in a string move to `next line` and  `align right` in Html editor ajax control and it should be hardcoded in my below code .

My code is

```
Editor1.Content = "No. J/" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem + "-" + TextBox1.Text + "-" + tyear + "/" + "     " + "/" + year + DateTime.Now.Day+"/"+DateTime.Now.Month+"/"+DateTime.Now.Year;
```

What i want is

> i want 5 blank spaces after
>
> ....`+ tyear + "/" + "`....

```
Move to next/new line after
....." + "/" + year +....
```

> Apply Align left to this entire
>   content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add blank spaces to the `&nbsp;` keyword. Normal blank spaces will be ignored as whitespace by the HTML parser.

Comment: For next line add a `<br/>` tag.